# Does correct bond lengths and angles imply that water is in a potential minimum?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water

So I come from the math community (so please disregard my ignorance on the topic).

If I have a water molecule and write the potential energy surface associated with it, my understanding is that I will find that the atoms configuration minimizes the potential energy function, so it will be a critical point of the potential energy surface.

My question is: suppose I have the building blocks of water, i.e 2 hydrogens and an oxygen, if it were the case by some magic, I added energy to the system that resulted the correct bond length and angles that correspond to water. Does that mean I have the water? That is to say ,geometrically, that I have taken a trajectory from the original potential minimum of just the original building blocks to a new potential minimum by adding energy. Since this new configuration has the correct bond length and angles, and potential energy, does that mean this atom configuration must indeed be water?

Thank you.

Comment: A water molecule (in its equilibrium geometry) has far less energy than three isolated atoms. So you should be taking energy away, not adding it. Now, if you’re saying that you hurl three atoms together and they coincidentally happen to form water, then that’s ok, but your water molecule would need to have a *lot* of kinetic energy to ensure that energy is conserved. In practice it would likely fall apart right after that. I know I’m not addressing your actual question, but I am slightly confused by why you’re adding energy.

Comment: hey @orthocresol thanks for answering me - I was thinking of the classical experiment where you apply a flame to hydrogen and oxygen to form water, for example. In that instance I would think you would be adding energy to the system, and for energy to be conserved, the hydrogen explodes causing water.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, in that experiment the energy still goes somewhere – I presume it heats the water up. In that experiment, there aren't any atoms lying around: all the hydrogens are $\ce{H2}$ and all the oxygens are $\ce{O2}$, so it's a bit different from the picture that your question evokes, which is more like having two individual atoms of hydrogen, plus one individual atom of oxygen.

Comment: Now, I think, if I am understanding your question correctly, that the answer is "yes". The water molecule *is* defined precisely by it having three atoms in that particular geometry, so "having a molecule of water" $\Leftrightarrow$ "having two hydrogen atoms and an oxygen atom in that particular geometry". I don't know if any chemistry book would explicitly state that, but that is definitely the understanding amongst chemists.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - the forward forward direction is obvious to me, but I wasn't sure if things were clean cut the other direction. Thank you so much!

Comment: It is not quite as simple. Geometry _plus electron density_ defines the molecule; geometry alone doesn't. If your orbitals aren't set right, then the molecule with correct bond lengths and angles might be in a forced and unstable state, which will fall apart the moment you turn off the magic.

Comment: The point is that by some magic makes everything possible. But in this case you won't be able to minimise anything. It is just that you, by chance, putted the right energy to the undefined dots. If you use real atoms, no. It is a bit hard to follow your reasoning. See Ivan Neretin above, too. If they are real H and O than it can be a water so excited that it does not exist but seen in a geometrical minimum.

Comment: Hi @IvanNeretin and Alchimista, thanks a lot for adding onto the comment. Specifically, pointing to DFT as being important - it was on my radar, but knowing that a correct geometry does not necessarily imply the orbitals are correct is an extremely helpful comment to know. From your comment Ivan, does looking at this problem from a classical perspective, rather than a quantum chemistry perspective, spell a recipe for doom?

Comment: Depends on what *doom* means for you, but one can set up rather "classical" equations $E(angle, bondlenghts)$ that describe the hyperpotential around the energy minimum quite accurately. Of course to *predict* it, you need the full-blown QM approach.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Fair, but having talked about nuclear positions and electronic states, should you not also then start considering vibrational states too?

Comment: I guess, perhaps the distinction is whether you want to identify it as *water* (as per your last sentence), or a *potential minimum* (as per title). I'd still argue that the atoms in the right geometry do specify water, but I definitely agree that it isn't necessarily a minimum (in general it would be some highly unstable state that will dissociate, as mentioned by others).

Comment: Perhaps the right geometry for a time substantially longer than the vibrational frequency. I can imagine an OH molecule in a neutral atomic hydrogen beam, with a hydrogen just skimming by and being in the ‘right’ geometry the moment you look at it. Yet it is not ‘water’ in any real sense.